# Return multipart body with RestRserve?

Tags: r, multipartform-data, restrserve

Can `RestRserve` return multiple files via multipart/form-data? I've tried using `set_body(c("file"=path))` and it returns the file content as per [documentation](https://restrserve.org/reference/Response.html#examples). This doesn't work with several files, however, as a list of filenames will be returned and not their content.

```
# load packages
library(readr)
library(callr)
library(httr)

# run RestRserve in the background
ps <- r_bg(function() {
  library(RestRserve)
  library(readr)

  app = Application$new()

  app$add_get(path = "/oneFile", FUN = function(request, response) {
    tmp1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    write_csv(head(iris, 3), tmp1)
    response$set_body(c("file"=tmp1))
  })

  app$add_get(path = "/twoFiles", FUN = function(request, response) {
    tmp1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    write_csv(head(iris, 3), tmp1)
    tmp2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    write_csv(tail(iris, 3), tmp2)  
    response$set_body(c("file"=tmp1, "file"=tmp2))
  })

  backend = BackendRserve$new()
  backend$start(app, http_port = 65080)
})

# wait for up
Sys.sleep(2L)

# check is alive
ps$is_alive()

# test endpoints
rs1 <- GET(url = "http:/127.0.0.1:65080/oneFile")
cat(content(rs1, encoding = 'UTF-8'))
#> Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width,Species
#> 5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
#> 4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
#> 4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa

rs2 <- GET(url = "http:/127.0.0.1:65080/twoFiles")
cat(content(rs2, encoding = 'UTF-8'))
#> C:\Users\platinov\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpekJ82H\file211c79eec27.csv
#> C:\Users\platinov\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpekJ82H\file211c68243bc6.csv

# kill background prcoess
ps$kill()
rm(ps)
```

Comment: I would say this is not something common. As of now RestRserve doesn't support such thing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to give some context: we are using RestRserve to implement a service that processes an input dataset according to a set of instructions (R code). In addition to the output data we’d like to return some metrics, e.g. if the requested operation is aggregation, we’d like to report the number of observations in each group. The simplest solution would be to return a multipart body with the processed data and metrics as files.

Comment: Could you describe what answer you expect? Link to RFC also would be helpful.